# Проблема с многопоточностью в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Впервые столкнулся с многопоточностью в Python из-за того, что окно tkinter моего плеера при проигрывании музыки зависает.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from playsound import playsound
import threading

def sound1():
    path = r'C:/sound'
    for sound in os.listdir(path):
        playsound('%s/%s' % (path, sound)) 

def quit():
    root1.quit()

def wind():
    global root1
    root1 = Tk()
    btn1 = Button(text="Запустить проигрыватель", command=sound1)
    btn2 = Button(text="Выйти", command=quit)
    btn1.pack()
    btn2.pack()
    root1.mainloop()
t = threading.Thread(target=wind).start()
j = threading.Thread(target=sound1).start()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы окно и аудио могли работать одновременно в моём случае?

Comment: Код из вопроса сразу же после запуска случаем не закрывается? А Tk разве будет работать в другом, не в главном потоке?

Comment: Нет, он работает, но само окно напрочь зависает, т.к работает аудио в главном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В Python лучше использовать ООП стиль программирования код будет более читабельным и простым в разработке.**

*Вообще сам скрипт надо рассматривать как основной поток 
Почему не работает многопоточность в скрипте выше ?
Потому что надо создать tkinter окно вызвать mainllop запустится бесконечный процесс и окно будет обновляться каждый проход по скрипту но так как у автора  запущенна функция playsound она остановится только тогда когда закончится воспроизведение музыки поэтому происходит эффект зависания что бы этого не произошло нужно playsound запустить в другом потоке и tkinter нечего не будет мешать вечно циклить)*

```
# в первых 4 строках импортируем необходимые модули 
import os
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import Tk, Button, DISABLED, mainloop
from playsound import playsound


class Player(Tk):                                     # объявление класса
    path = r'C:/sound'                                # путь поиска музыки 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                            # наледование нашим классом класса Tk
        self.initUI()                                 # вызов функции

    def initUI(self):                                 # функция построения интерфейса
        self.play_button = Button(self, text="Запустить проигрыватель", 
            command=self.run)                         # создаём кнопку при нажатии на которую происходит вызов функции self.run
        exit_button = Button(self, text="Выйти", command=self.quit) # кнопка выхода 
        self.play_button.pack()                       # размещение кнопок в окне "смотри документацию tkinter"
        exit_button.pack()


    def run(self): 
        self.play_button["state"] = DISABLED
        def play():                                   # создаём функцию для воспроизведения муз. файлов  
            for sound in os.listdir(self.path):       # получаем список всех муз. файлов в директории  
                playsound('%s/%s' % (self.path, sound)) # вызов функции с параметрами 
        thread = Thread(target=play)                    # создание потока 
        thread.daemon = True                            # поток умрёт вместе с основным 
        thread.start()                                  # запуск потока 

    def quit(self):
        quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    player = Player()
    player.mainloop()
```

Comment: Только если соберёте через pyinstaller в EXE файле функция quit() может не сработать...

Comment: код без объяснения мало поможет будущим читателям с похожей проблемой и даже сам автор может не понять почему исходная проблема возникла. См. [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Comment: вы можете написать: `command=self.destroy`, чтобы покинуть GUI

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import os, time, threading


def path_files(path=os.getcwd()):
    """получить только файлы, из path-каталога, и всех его под-директорий"""
    for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
        yield from (os.path.join(root, file) for file in files)  # вернуть файлы директории
        for folder in dirs:  # обойти под-директории рекурсивно
            yield from path_files(path=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, folder)))


def sound1(path=r'C:/sound') -> None:
    """какаято функция playsound"""
    for file in path_files(path):
        time.sleep(1)  # задержка-зависание, для примера
        print(file)  # playsound(file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root1 = Tk()
    btn1 = Button(text="Запустить проигрыватель",
                  command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=sound1, daemon=True).start())
    btn2 = Button(text="Выйти", command=root1.destroy)
    btn1.pack()
    btn2.pack()
    root1.mainloop()
```